# Add partial view in layout with controller and also using area

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have started using asp .net mvc and I am getting some trouble with the routing. I want to have a partial view in the layout file. I also have areas. My routing is as follows:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { area = "Home", controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
    null
).DataTokens.Add("area", "Home");

// home and error page
routes.MapRoute("", "error", new { area = "", controller = "Home", action = "Error" });
routes.MapRoute("home_default", "", new { area = "Home", controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

I am trying to use

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("Index", "_Menu"); }
```

in the layout file. I have define a `_Menu` controller in the controllers folder outside the areas. I am actually getting

> The controller for path '/project/' was not found or does not implement IController.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Calling:

```
Html.RenderAction("Index", "_Menu");
```

Is exactly the same as calling this [RenderAction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.childactionextensions.renderaction(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.RenderAction%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary%29):

```
Html.RenderAction("Index", "_Menu", new { area = "<currentArea>" });
```

So if you want to make sure a call is to the non-area controller you need to:

```
Html.RenderAction("Index", "_Menu", new { area = ""});
```

Comment: I cannot assign an area to null, and if i assign it to empty string i get  "No route in the route table matches the supplied values." error